# Как првязать кости к скачаной моделе в блендере

Tags: анимация, 3d, blender

Подскажите пожалуйста есть модель  (приложил) так вот при попытке наложить скелет на модель (через автоматическое распределение весов) правильно двигается только половина модели. Причём вторая половина модели двигается в след за первой не отдельно. Пример машу правой рукой - машет и левая, хотя должна махать только правая.
Где я не прав?
Пробовал скелет привязать к модели по костям - одну за другой, но модель выделяется вся и я не могу привязать условеное запястье к запястью.
Как мне подготовить скачанную модель чтобы я мог спокойно привязать ее к костям?
Делаю вот по этому уроку, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6ZCySIVe90&t=520s  но на шаге прязать кость к конкретному эллементу затык т.к. выделяется вся модель, а не запястье, хотя кость внутри есть.
Как быть?
Ссылка на модель https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EsK3NtO19QjxkLRAN3NrYtQo8CE0J6F7/view?usp=drive_link