# Как првязать кости к скачаной моделе в блендере

Tags: blender

Подскажите пожалуйста есть модель  (приложил) так вот при попытке наложить скелет на модель (через автоматическое распределение весов) правильно двигается только половина модели. Причём вторая половина модели двигается в след за первой не отдельно. Пример машу правой рукой - машет и левая, хотя должна махать только правая.
Где я не прав?
Пробовал скелет привязать к модели по костям - одну за другой, но модель выделяется вся и я не могу привязать условеное запястье к запястью.
Как мне подготовить скачанную модель чтобы я мог спокойно привязать ее к костям?
Делаю вот по этому уроку, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6ZCySIVe90&t=520s  но на шаге прязать кость к конкретному эллементу затык т.к. выделяется вся модель, а не запястье, хотя кость внутри есть.
Как быть?
Ссылка на модель https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EsK3NtO19QjxkLRAN3NrYtQo8CE0J6F7/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Как првязать кости к скачаной моделе в блендере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1547812/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как првязать кости к скачаной моделе в блендере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1547812/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)